# Change background color after first rendering, but the background transition animations sometimes don't show

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, css-transitions

Render 5 `Mid` components.

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Mid />
      <Mid />
      <Mid />
      <Mid />
      <Mid />
    </>
  );
};
```

`Mid` is to get the data and only show the `Block` if the data is not empty

```
const Mid = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const t = setTimeout(() => {
      setData([]);
    }, 500);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(t);
    };
  }, []);

  if (data) {
    return <Block />;
  }
  return null;
};
```

`Block` has set css transition. After it first rendering, changed the background color in `useEffect`.

```
const Block = () => {
  const eleRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    eleRef.current.style.background = "green";
  }, []);

  return (
    <span
      ref={eleRef}
      style={{
        transition: "background 5s",
        background: "#ccc",
        margin: 4,
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

I hope to see every `Block` has the background transition animations when it first rendered, but some of them has no animation.

Here is the online demo and gif.

[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/transition-question-3x1sc0?file=/src/App.tsx)

[image]

What is the cause?

Comment: Enivia, what kind or order do you want, do you want to show first box first and so on? Could you please explain it in little detail, what you are expecting and what is not working.

Comment: @SarojShrestha I want see every `Block` has the transition animations when it first rendered, but the animation just appears randomly

Comment: Do you mean the last block is not working properly? Other blocks are working fine? Or none of them are working as expected?

Comment: In this gif last block is not working as expected.